# Twitter Bootstrap validation not working in WordPress theme.

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a theme in WordPress and it works ok but I cannot get Twitter Bootstrap validation to work, been stuck for a few weeks now. 
Here's functions.php folder:

```
<?php

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );  //Adds thumbnails compatibility to the theme 
// set_post_thumbnail_size( 250, 250 ); // 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall, resize mode

function dsm_portfolio_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dsm_portfolio_styles'); 

function dsm_javascript_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('jqBootstrapValidation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script('contact_me', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/contact_me.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script('freelancer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/freelancer.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script('scrollspy', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scrollspy.js', array('jquery'), '', true );



}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dsm_javascript_scripts');
```

and form on index.php page:

```
<!-- Contact Section -->
 <section id="Contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Contact Me</h2>
                <hr class="star-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <!-- To configure the contact form email address, go to mail/contact_me.php and update the email address in the PHP file on line 19. -->
                <!-- The form should work on most web servers, but if the form is not working you may need to configure your web server differently. -->
                <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate action="http://formspree.io/daniel@mobbzys.co.uk" method="POST">
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                            <input name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks in advanced guys.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this script in footer.

```
<script>
  $(function () { $("input,select,textarea").not("type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(); } );
</script>
```

[working fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/g2r5123z/2/)

Comment: it didn't work. added in the footer.php folder but still not working.